# Función doble clic en registro

Tags: html, jquery, datatables

Fíjense que tengo una tabla hecha con Datatables, y para los datos dos modales, una para agregar registros y la otra para actualizar registros. En la modal de actualizar registros, le doy clic al botón editar y me carga la modal con los datos a editar, pero quisiera agregar la funcionalidad de que al hacer doble clic en el registro también se abra la modal solo con fines de volverla más práctica a la hora de editar.

Este es el formulario de editar datos:

```html
<div class="modal fade" id="modalActualizar" data-backdrop="static" data-keyboard="false" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="labelActualizarDatos" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <h5 class="modal-title" id="labelActualizarDatos">Actualizar ordenes</h5>
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
          </button>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          <div class="card">
            <div class="card-body">
              <nav class="mb-3">
                <div class="nav nav-tabs" id="nav-tab" role="tablist">
                  <a class="nav-item nav-link active" id="nav-actualizar-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#nav-actualizar" role="tab" aria-controls="nav-actualizar" aria-selected="true">Actualizar</a>
                </div>
              </nav>
              <div class="tab-content" id="nav-tabContent">
                <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="nav-actualizar" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="nav-actualizar-tab">
                  <form id="formularioActualizar">
                    <div class="row">
                      <div class="form-group col-12 col-sm-2 col-md-2 col-lg-2 col-xl-2">
                        <label for="condicion-Actualizador">Condicion</label>
                        <input type="text" name="condicion-Actualizador" class="form-control awesomplete" id="condicion-Actualizador" value="<?php echo $losdatos->condicion; ?>" nombre="condicion" db="condicion" maxlength="150">
                      </div>
                      <div class="form-group col-12 col-sm-2 col-md-2 col-lg-2 col-xl-2">
                        <label for="orden-Actualizador">ORDEN</label>
                        <input type="text" name="orden-Actualizador" class="form-control  " id="orden-Actualizador" value="<?php echo $losdatos->orden; ?>" maxlength="8">
                      </div>
                      <div class="form-group col-12 col-sm-7 col-md-7 col-lg-7 col-xl-7">
                        <label for="cliente-Actualizador">CLIENTE</label>
                        <input type="text" name="cliente-Actualizador" class="form-control awesomplete " id="cliente-Actualizador" value="<?php echo $losdatos->cliente; ?>" nombre="nombre" db="clientes" maxlength="150">
                      </div>
                      <div class="form-group col-12 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4 col-xl-4">
                        <label for="marca-Actualizador">MARCA</label>
                        <select class="form-control " id="marca-Actualizador" name="marca-Actualizador" nombre="marca" db="marca">
                          <?php echo '<option value="' . $losdatos->marca . '" selected>' . $losdatos->marca . '</option>'; ?>
                          <option value=""></option>
                        </select>
                      </div>
                      <div class="form-group col-12 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4 col-xl-4">
                        <label for="modelo-Actualizador">MODELO</label>
                        <input type="text" name="modelo-Actualizador" class="form-control  " id="modelo-Actualizador" value="<?php echo $losdatos->modelo; ?>" maxlength="150">
                      </div>
                      <div class="form-group col-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12 col-xl-12">
                        <label for="problema-Actualizador">PROBLEMA</label>
                        <textarea class="form-control " id="problema-Actualizador" name="problema-Actualizador" cols="30" rows="3">
                          <?php echo $losdatos->problema; ?>
                        </textarea>
                      </div>
                      <div class="form-group col-sm-12">
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary elboton" data-dismiss="modal">Actualizar Datos</button>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </form>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    </div>
```

Ya ejecuté la función con este script, pero no sé por qué no me abre :(

```
$('#formularioActualizar').on('dblclick', 'tr', function() {
  var data = tabla.row(this).data();
  $('#modalActualizar').modal('show');
  // ... continuar con los demás campos y datos que deseas cargar en la modal
});
```

Comment: ¿Y el/los `tr` de _formularioActualizar_ dónde están?

Comment: No tiene.
Los que si tienen son la tabla donde se ven los registros.

Comment: Entonces por eso no se dispara tu evento...